# Rails - Display flash notice before running method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a method in my controller index action, `add_product_data`, which basically updates product data if the `title` of the first or last product is `nil`. I would like a flash message to display if the `title` of the first or last product is `nil`, before the `add_product_data` method is called, so that the user knows why the request is taking so long.

What I have:

```
def index
  if params["rating_set_id"]
    @products = Product.find(:all, :joins => :rating_sets, :conditions => ["rating_set_id = ?", params["rating_set_id"]])
    if @products.first.title.nil? && @products.last.title.nil?
      redirect_to :back, :flash => { :notice => "Updating missing product data..." }
      FetchRec.add_product_data(@products) 
    end

    @rating_set = RatingSet.find(params["rating_set_id"])
    @unique_dept = Product.find_by_sql("SELECT dept FROM products WHERE dept <> '' GROUP BY dept")
  else
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

As I have it set up, the flash message displays after the product data is added and the request is made. How can I display the flash message when the request is made, and if the `add_product_data` method needs to be called.

Comment: If you want to run something as a separate process, then do so--you're misunderstanding how standard synchronous web stuff works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a long-running request, you can use an async runner such as [Sidekiq](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq%20Sidekiq) and return a 202 (Accepted) with the flash message. There is no way in "standard" HTTP/HTML to show a message before a request completes.